# Put method is not working in OpenStack

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I used below method to get Auth-token and i got the output as below.But if use that id as Auth-token  for PUT method it's not working it's showing as explained below.

curl -sd '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "admin", "password": "password"}}}' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://169.0.0.11:5000/v2.0/tokens | python -m json.tool

```
{
"access": {
    "metadata": {
        "is_admin": 0,
        "roles": []
    },
    "serviceCatalog": [],
    "token": {
        "audit_ids": [
            "GgpxHyihQVyuI1ryerQZVw"
        ],
        "expires": "2016-08-15T16:11:49Z",
        "id": "bcced26a96304e8197fa85e110df9aa2",
        "issued_at": "2016-08-15T15:11:49.386446"
    },
    "user": {
        "id": "a5064af3b125449a9a09e9b69966f843",
        "name": "admin",
        "roles": [],
        "roles_links": [],
        "username": "admin"
    }
}
```

}

curl -i -X PUT "X-Auth-Token:bcced26a96304e8197fa85e110df9aa2"          http://169.0.0.11/dashboard/project/containers/test/mymusic/
but  its saying that                                                                          Could not resolve host: X-AUTH-TOKEN                                       HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
can any one help me to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have missed to add `-H` for Header, rest looks fine.

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token:bcced26a96304e8197fa85e110df9aa2" http://169.0.0.11/dashboard/project/containers/test/mymusic/
```

Comment: thanks.Yes after using H also i am getting the same error                                                              301 moved permenently

Comment: Can you login to Dashboard from browser and then paste the URL? is it accessible?, generally when accessing REST API, you need to provide ports, as services run in different port such as glance in 9292 etc?

Comment: Ya .I can login through browser and I used that URL only